# Слово "гном"

Tags: этимология

Во-первых, всех от души поздравляю с Новым годом!!
А во-вторых, уже мой вопрос.
Я - большой поклонник творчества Толкиена. Так вот, я читала, что слово "гном" было придумано им и означает оно "знающий" и все в таком роде. Изначально оно даже не относилось к подгорному народу, но сейчас не об этом.
Действительно ли до Толкиена их не называли гномами, а были только карлики, дварфы и кто там еще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря Черных

Гном. В русском языке слово известно с  начала 19 века. В других языках: Gnom (нем.),  gnome (фр.),  gnomo (исп. и итал.), первоисточник - новолатинское gnomus, искусственно образовано ученым эпохи Возрождения Парацельсом, сложение греческого (земля + местопребывание).

С другой стороны, Парацельс мог использовать уже готовое слово. В древнегреческой литературе есть понятие "гнома" (gnome) - краткое нравоучительное изречение. Гномы были очень популярны среди философов, ораторов, софистов.

Answer (score 2):

Да нет конечно. )))
Моджно подумать, что до Толкиена и фольклора в Европе не было )))

> Гномы — сказочные карлики из западноевропейского, в первую очередь германо-скандинавского, фольклора, частые герои сказок и легенд[1][2]. Известны в разных языках под названиями «дверг» (др.-сканд. dvergr, мн.ч. dvergar), «цверг» (нем. zwergen), «дворф» (англ. dwarfs), «краснолюд» (польск. krasnoludki), а также, в древности, «нибелунги» и «нижние альвы». Согласно сказаниям, они живут под землёй, носят бороды и славятся богатством и мастерством.
>
> Принятое в русском языке слово «гном» (вероятно, от греч. Γνώση — знание, лат. — Gnomus), как считается, изобрёл алхимик Парацельс в XVI веке[3]. В алхимии и оккультизме гном — дух земли как первоэлемента, земная элементаль (см. гномы в алхимии). Гномы, наряду с эльфами, гоблинами и троллями, часто появляются в литературе жанра фэнтези и ролевых играх.

(вики)

Добавлю только, что гномы и дворфы на мой вкус совершенно разные "звери". Первые - преимущественно лесные жители, маленькие и физически слабые, но весьма интеллектуальные. 
Вторые - прямолинейные крепыши, занятые преимущественно на физической работе.
Это не по Толкиену, это анализ современного понимания.

Ну а Толькиен, видимо, просто внес, позаимствовав у Парацельса, это слово в английский словарь.

Comment: При чем тут фольклор? Речь о названии. Просто, до Толкиена их могли называть иначе - я об этом ясно в своем вопросе написала.

Comment: Нет, я такого в вашем вопросе не уловил. 
Называли их по-разному, гномами - тоже. Но не в английской традицию Только и всего.